# Economics Masters Courses?

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory

I want to do an economics masters course (not a PHD) in the UK or US preferably with a focus on game theory, auction theory, mechanism design and contract theory though I understand I'll probably have to take at least one macro and metrics course.

I found that NYU has an MA in econ and has good game theory (by Ariel Rubinstein) but are there any others?

Comment: are these questions on-topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Economics as defined in the [FAQ](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website will be helpful.
Ask that in here.
http://www.urch.com/forums/phd-economics